# MVC 3 with NHibernate Pagination

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate, pagination

I have find some questions and answer to how to do pagination with NHibernate, I have a code as follows:

```
public virtual List<T> GetPageResults(int pageIndex, int pageSize)
        {
            using (var session = SessionFactory.OpenSession())
            {
                var returnVal =
                    session.CreateCriteria<T>().SetFirstResult(pageIndex).SetMaxResults(pageSize).Future
                        <T>().OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).ToList();

                return returnVal;
            }
        }
```

As you can see I m doing the pagination with OrderByDescending, I want to display the last item first. Is this a good way of doing this?

Also, is there any framework i can use that will provide me the pagination easily, I see lot of packages but most of them has close to no documentation except SO questions.

thanks.

Comment: can u recommend a framework to handle pagination in UI ? looks like there are tons but none has concise documentation of doing things.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? As in being able to specify something like http://mysite.com/users/page12 and the framework automatically setting the criteria? Or did you have something else in mind?

Comment: I can handle the controller and data but I am looking for a framework that will generate the UI easily for me. Right now I m doing it myself. manual stuff. I looked at mvccontrib but no documentation just couple blog posts.

Comment: I've used Telerik extensions for MVC, but not sure if you're looking for a grid or not http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query you can write with QueryOver:

```
session.QueryOver<T>()
  .OrderBy(t => t.Property).Desc
  .Skip(pageIndex).Take(pageSize)
  .List();
```

Comment: QueryOver combines the use of Extension Methods and Lambda Expressions to provide a statically typesafe wrapper round the ICriteria API. It's the same ICriteria with Lambda Expressions
http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/12/17/queryover-in-nh-3-0.aspx